# Неправильно выполняется сравнение дат JAVA

Tags: java

Всем привет! Выполняя одно задание, столкнулся с тем, что неправильно сортируются даты. Пробовал начать использовать тип Calendar, но также ничего не вышло. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка.

```
class KeyComp implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // right order:
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас сравниваются строки а не даты.

Надо String конвертировать в Date.
[пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date)

```
class KeyComp implements Comparator<Date> {
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        // right order:
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```